# PDOException when adding new content

Tags: nodes

when adding content (node/add/article in UI) i get this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '147' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {node} (nid, vid, type, language, title, uid, status, created, changed, comment, promote, sticky, tnid, translate) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12, :db_insert_placeholder_13); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 147 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 147 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => article [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => fa [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => rewq [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 1354548748 [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 1354548748 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 2 [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_13] => 0 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7114 of /var/www/vhosts/******/httpdocs/includes/common.inc).
```

I've read if I upgrade my php to 5.4 (from current 5.3) it will be solved
Is there not any easier option? ( well it wont be easy for my upgrading php on this particular server right now)

I also changed `node` table structure, set `vid` default value from NULL to 0 ( it was mention somewhere on drupal.org) but no change

tanx in advance

Comment: That'a MySQL error, nothing to do with PHP...you'll receive exactly the same error no matter what version of PHP you're using. Upgrading won't fix anything. How are you adding this content, through the UI?

Comment: Also, it'd be good to check for any pending database updates (70xx) in Drupal and run them.